# Debugging a netTcp WCF binding

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security

I have a `netTcp WCF` service running in a windows service on a remote machine.
The windows service is running as user `mydomain\u2`

The `.config` file for the windows service hosted WCF is

```
<security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="None" />
</security>
```

Now when I run

> svcutil.exe http://wcfhostmachine:8000/MyWCFService?wsdl

The client `output.config` has the following security portion:

```
<security mode="None">
     <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
     <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
</security>
```

They are different. ***WHY?? SHOULD I CHANGE THE CLIENT TO MATCH THE SERVER??***

While I can still send instructions to the `WCF` service and they are processed, when Visual Studio tries to step into the `WCF` code running on the remote host, I get the infamous:

*Unable to automatically debug '....'. Connecting to the server machine failed. The Visual Studio remote debugger on the target computer cannot connect back to this computer. Ensure that `DNS` is correctly configured on the target computer.*

Needless to say `DNS` is fine.

The only other reason I can think of why I am running into this situation is because my Visual Studio is running as `mydomain\u1` and the service is running on the remote machine as `mydomain\u2`.

**Has any one faced/solved this issue in the past?**

**MORE INFO**

Below is my App.config for the host service. Could I be encountering this issue because I don't have a mex endpoint?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="my.Indexer" behaviorConfiguration="IndexerServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://hostmachine:8000/Indexer"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://hostmachine:9000/Indexer"
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="Binding1"
                  contract="my.IIndexer" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="Binding1"
                     hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                     sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                     transferMode="Buffered"
                     portSharingEnabled="false">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>

        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="IndexerServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same - all that's relevant in this case is the mode="None" on both ends. The rest inside the `<security>` tag is totally irrelevant once you've set mode to None.

What the svcutil.exe creates are just the system defaults.

Marc

Comment: Good to know -- thanks.
I'll leave the question open for now to see if others can chime in on why I can't debug still....